# How can I style the border-radius of a mat-form-field in Angular?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material

```
  <mat-form-field class="new-inputs" style="border-radius: 10px;">
                <mat-label>Ime</mat-label>
                <input matInput type="text" maxlength="15"  id="firstName" formControlName="firstName" required
                       [class.ng-invalid]="userData.get('firstName')?.invalid && userData.get('firstName')?.touched"
                       [class.ng-touched]="userData.get('firstName')?.touched">
               <!-- <input matInput style="font-weight: normal">-->
              </mat-form-field>
```

I am trying to edit the mat-form-field border-radius, but i can't seem to get it to work
I am using the normal mat-form-field without apperance, i dont know if thats a mistake or not
The current form field is not up to design standards, and needs to be changed

If I edit it in f12 console the border radius changes,  but otherwise I've only been able to change the placeholder from bold to normal, and background color (even that is a little bit buggy, but it does not bother me)
i've tried ng-deep, but it says its deprecated

Answer (score 3):

The CSS for editing the Mat-Form-Field border-radius is,

This edits the left-side border-radius

```
.mdc-notched-outline__leading {
  border-top-left-radius: 8px !important;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px !important;
}
```

This edits the right-side border-radius

```
.mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
  border-top-right-radius: 8px !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px !important;
}
```

Make sure you add this in style.css to have it applied to all your elements.

If only required for a specific mat-form-field, then declare a custom class and add the CSS with the custom class as Prefix.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you are looking for `fieldset`.

This is how it should be.

```
<fieldset style="border-radius:10px;">
 <legend>My Title</legend>
  <mat-form-field class="new-inputs">
     <mat-label>Ime</mat-label>
     <input matInput type="text" maxlength="15"  id="firstName" formControlName="firstName" required
        [class.ng-invalid]="userData.get('firstName')?.invalid && userData.get('firstName')?.touched"
        [class.ng-touched]="userData.get('firstName')?.touched">
     <!-- <input matInput style="font-weight: normal">-->
   </mat-form-field>
</fieldset>
```

If not so, maybe your looking for the border of this *border-radius:10px;* that you setted up. But you are not seing the effect of the `border-radius` 'cause this  have no border in the first place.

Therefore, you need to set it's border first then add a *border-radius*.

```
<mat-form-field class="new-inputs" style="border:1px solid blue;border-radius:10px;">
     <mat-label>Ime</mat-label>
     <input matInput type="text" maxlength="15"  id="firstName" formControlName="firstName" required
        [class.ng-invalid]="userData.get('firstName')?.invalid && userData.get('firstName')?.touched"
        [class.ng-touched]="userData.get('firstName')?.touched">
     <!-- <input matInput style="font-weight: normal">-->
</mat-form-field>
```

Maybe this will answer your question or not, but hoping it will help you in some ways.